Axios onUploadProgress return immidiately `upload=total`
I'm calling onUploadProgress event to updat eprogress bar when uploading files but for some reason the uploaded=total immidiately even though its not the case...
Here is my code:
  async create(user: UserEntity, uploadedFile: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(uploadedFile, user)
    const storageKey = `files/${new Date().getTime()}-${slugify(uploadedFile.originalname)}`;
    console.log(storageKey)
    const url = await this._uploadService.save(storageKey, uploadedFile.buffer, uploadedFile.mimetype);
    console.log(url)
    if (!url) {
      throw new BadRequestException(ErrorMessages.FILE_UPLOAD_FAILED);
    }

    return this._fileRepository.save(
      new FileEntity({
        originalname: uploadedFile.originalname,
        mimetype: uploadedFile.mimetype,
        size: uploadedFile.size,
        url,
        storageKey,
        user
      }),
    );
  }

Where
 async save(storageKey: string, buffer: Buffer, contentType = 'image/jpg') {
    return this._s3
      .upload({
        Bucket: this.configService.get('aws.s3BucketName', { infer: true }),
        Body: buffer,
        Key: storageKey,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: contentType,
      })
      .promise()
      .then((value) => `${this.configService.get('aws.s3Endpoint', { infer: true })}/${value.Key}`);
  }

    axios
      .post<UploadedFile>(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/file`, formData, {
        onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
          setFiles((prevState) =>
            prevState.map((item) => {
              if (item === file)
                return {
                  ...file,
                  progress: Math.floor((loaded / total!) * 100),
                };
              return item;
            })
          );

          if (loaded == total) {
            // TODO: Get the files from database
            setUploadedFiles([...uploadedFiles]);
          }
        },
      })
      .catch(console.error);

It took (20mb file): POST to /file took 15323ms
